# Snapshots backup problems Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: partitioning, backup, btrfs, snapshot, 23.10

I tried to use Timeshift for a snapshot backup but when I installed it , it can not find my root partition as it is not in a shape like `/@`
and `/@home`.

How to get that ?

I am using Ubuntu 23.10.

During installation I did manual partitioning :

- `ext4` and `fat32` for `/boot`
- `/` as `btrfs` (root)
- `/home` as `btrfs`

Or if is easier to setup `snapper` or `btrbk` for snapshots , can someone guide me or share some good guide for noobs?

Comment: It is Ubuntu 23.10

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 23.10 and Timeshift also, but I opted to use the rsync solution and set about marking the snapshot to include all root and home files. so far I have not experienced any problems. Timeshift has no problems finding my / and /home directories. I store the snapshots on a backup drive formatted NTFS. Try it my way and see if it works for you.